# How to call onNewIntent() of Activity from a service

Tags: android, android-intent

How to execute onNewIntent() of Activity from a sevice? What are flags to be given while firing the intent??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override this method if you want to do some thing 
    for notification as an example

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(com.example.xyz.R.drawable.ic_launcher,message1, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,com.example.xyz.DemoActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE",pkgName);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("APP_STATUS", AppStatus);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("APP_NAME",AppName);
    //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will update the notification 
    PendingIntent intent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message1, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

and my DemoActivity.class looks likes

```
       public class DemoActivity extends Activity{

 public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.android.APP_CLOUD_DELETE_APK";
 private TextView  messsageText,NotificationHeader;
 private Button okButton;
 private int AppStatusId;
 private String PkgName,app_name,ApkFileName;
 private RegisterTask mRegisterTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo_activity);
    //  if this activity is not  in stack , this mwthod will be called


}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // if this activity is in stack , this mwthod will be called
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `onNewIntent` by self it'll called by the system. If your activity can handle fired intent then it will be called automatically, check your intent and related intent filter.

This is only called when you activity is singletop and your activity's Oncreate has already been called.

Comment: Do I need to give something in intent filter??